# How to select value from a python dictionary with multi items

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to get values from a python dictionary. As you can see below I have this example. I would like to get only keys which start with `"BTC_"` and select it if its `"BTC"` Value is greater than 100.

```
d = { 
  'BTC_LTC':  { 'BTC': '138.13504038', 'LTC': '4662.34229096' }, 
  'BTC_MAID': { 'BTC': '10.38010322', 'MAID': '359919.71515255' },
  'BTC_NEM': { 'BTC': '30.34435435', 'NEM': '34435345' },
  'BTC_TRX': { 'BTC': '101.1122', 'TRX': '4546456456.343543543' },
  'USDC_BTC': { 'USDC': '481389.13175764', 'BTC': '74.73988488' },
  'USDC_ETH': { 'USDC': '72302.27016210', 'ETH': '357.72884034' },
  'totalBTC': '2340.96441558',
  'totalETH': '2771.63218462',
  'totalUSDC': '681255.56961992',
  'totalXMR': '267.83601213' 
}
```

The expected result is the following list:

```
['BTC_LTC', 'BTC_TRX']
```

Because of their key start with `"BTC_"` and their `'BTC'` value is greater than 100.

Comment: are the keys strings?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It's important that you to read the FAQ to know how to post a good question. In this case, you haven't yet answered: what have you tried so far?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf yes strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

assuming assign a variable for given dictionary

```py
a = { 
  'BTC_LTC':  { 'BTC': '138.13504038', 'LTC': '4662.34229096' }, 
  'BTC_MAID': { 'BTC': '10.38010322', 'MAID': '359919.71515255' },
  'BTC_NEM': { 'BTC': '30.34435435', 'NEM': '34435345' },
  'BTC_TRX': { 'BTC': '101.1122', 'TRX': '4546456456.343543543' },
  'USDC_BTC': { 'USDC': '481389.13175764', 'BTC': '74.73988488' },
  'USDC_ETH': { 'USDC': '72302.27016210', 'ETH': '357.72884034' },
  'totalBTC': '2340.96441558',
  'totalETH': '2771.63218462',
  'totalUSDC': '681255.56961992',
  'totalXMR': '267.83601213' 
}   
result = []
for k, v in a.items():
   if k.startswith('BTC') and float(v.get('BTC', 0)) > 100:
       result.append(k)
print(result)
```

in Python keys in dictionary must be immutable so your dictionary is not valid, you must convert keys to string or immutable object to use

https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

```
dic = { 
  BTC_LTC:  { BTC: '138.13504038', LTC: '4662.34229096' }, 
  BTC_MAID: { BTC: '10.38010322', MAID: '359919.71515255' },
  BTC_NEM: { BTC: '30.34435435', NEM: '34435345' },
  BTC_TRX: { BTC: '101.1122', TRX: '4546456456.343543543' },
  USDC_BTC: { USDC: '481389.13175764', BTC: '74.73988488' },
  USDC_ETH: { USDC: '72302.27016210', ETH: '357.72884034' },
  totalBTC: '2340.96441558',
  totalETH: '2771.63218462',
  totalUSDC: '681255.56961992',
  totalXMR: '267.83601213' 
}   

res = []
for i in dic:
    if isinstance(i,dict):
        if i['BTC']>100:
            res.append(i)

print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your keys are strings, you can use the following assigning your dictionary to a variable called `d`:

```
d = { 
  'BTC_LTC':  { 'BTC': '138.13504038', 'LTC': '4662.34229096' }, 
  'BTC_MAID': { 'BTC': '10.38010322', 'MAID': '359919.71515255' },
  'BTC_NEM': { 'BTC': '30.34435435', 'NEM': '34435345' },
  'BTC_TRX': { 'BTC': '101.1122', 'TRX': '4546456456.343543543' },
  'USDC_BTC': { 'USDC': '481389.13175764', 'BTC': '74.73988488' },
  'USDC_ETH': { 'USDC': '72302.27016210', 'ETH': '357.72884034' },
  'totalBTC': '2340.96441558',
  'totalETH': '2771.63218462',
  'totalUSDC': '681255.56961992',
  'totalXMR': '267.83601213' 
}   

>>> [k for k, v in d.items() if k.startswith('BTC_') and v.get('BTC', None) is not None and float(v.get('BTC')) > 100]

['BTC_LTC', 'BTC_TRX']
```

Answer (score 0):

Keys as strings, using a list comprehension:

```
inp = {
    'BTC_LTC':  { 'BTC': '138.13504038', 'LTC': '4662.34229096' },
    'BTC_MAID': { 'BTC': '10.38010322', 'MAID': '359919.71515255' },
    'BTC_NEM': { 'BTC': '30.34435435', 'NEM': '34435345' },
    'BTC_TRX': { 'BTC': '101.1122', 'TRX': '4546456456.343543543' },
    'USDC_BTC': { 'USDC': '481389.13175764', 'BTC': '74.73988488' },
    'USDC_ETH': { 'USDC': '72302.27016210', 'ETH': '357.72884034' },
    'totalBTC': '2340.96441558',
    'totalETH': '2771.63218462',
    'totalUSDC': '681255.56961992',
    'totalXMR': '267.83601213'
}

outp = [k for k, v in inp.items() if k[:4] == "BTC_" and float(v["BTC"]) > 100]

print(outp)
```